# Prove that RKHS of translation invriant kernel is a Hilbert space

Tags: fourier-transform, gaussian, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I am reading a lecture on RKHS of kernels and here is an exercise I have not been able to solve

Given a translation invariant kernel
$$
k(x,y) = \varphi (x-y)
$$

The theorem states that once $\varphi$ is symmetric and positive definite, and that $\varphi$ and $\hat\varphi$ are integrable, the RKHS would be
$$
\mathcal H = \left\{ f \in \mathcal C(\mathbb R) \cap L^2 (\mathbb R) \middle\vert \int \frac{\vert\hat f(\omega) \vert^2}{\hat \varphi(\omega)} \mathrm d \omega < \infty\right\}
$$
Where $\hat \ast$ denotes the Fourier transform of $\ast$.

Can anyone please show me why this is a Hilbert space, typically by showing that it is closed in $L^2(\mathbb R)$? Thank you

Comment: Can you give the complete statement of the theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Since $K(x,y) = \varphi (x-y)$, Bochner theorem tell us that there exists a nondecreasing measure $d\sigma(t)=\rho(t)\,dt$, with $\rho(t)>0$ and continuos, such that
$$\varphi(x-y) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{it(x-y)}d\sigma(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{it(x-y)}\rho(t)\,dt,$$ and we denote $\rho=\hat{\phi}$.

Let $F(x)$ being such that $g(x)=F(x)\sqrt{\rho(x)}$ is in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, that is $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}|F(x)|^2\rho(x)\,dx<\infty.$$ Then the function  $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}} F(t)\rho(t)e^{-ixt}dt$$ is in the reproducing kernel Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_K$, and you can see that
$$|f(x)|=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(F(t)\sqrt{\rho(t)}\right)\left(e^{-ixt}\sqrt{\rho(t)}\right)dt\right|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\|g\|_{L^2}\sqrt{K(x,x)} .$$ The [inversion formula to Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_inversion_theorem) gives us that
$$F(t)\rho(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{ixt}dx,$$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. It follows that $$\|f\|_{\mathcal{H}_K}^2=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}|F(t)|^2\rho(t)\,dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|F(t)\rho(t)\right|^2\frac{1}{\rho(t)}dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)e^{ixt}dx\right|^2\frac{1}{\rho(t)}dt.$$

Please see Theorem 2.1.2 in the book [Integral Transforms, Reproducing Kernels and Their Applications, by S. Saitoh](https://bookarchive.net/pdf/integral-transforms-reproducing-kernels-and-their-applications/).

You can find complementary discussions searching for "[\(\phi(x-y)\) Bochner theorem](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28%5Cphi%28x-y%29%5C%29%20Bochner%20theorem%20)" on SearchOnMath.